# How to set a docker container's iP?

Tags: containers, docker, openstack

Can somebody tell me how to set a container's ip to a specific one ? I dont want to set the bridge to set of ips. All the results i get in net is to set range of ips to the docker bridge.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an existing IP of the host like so:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:80:80 image etc.
```

Comment: always funny, that a new user cannot accept or vote on an answer :) You're welcome anyway