# Docker 1.10 container's IP in LAN

Tags: networking, docker

Since Docker 1.10 (and libnetwork update) we can manually give an IP to a container inside a user-defined network, and that's cool!

I want to give a container an IP address in my LAN (like we can do with Virtual Machines in "bridge" mode). My LAN is 192.168.1.0/24, all my computers have IP addresses inside it. And I want my containers having IPs in this range, in order to reach them from anywhere in my LAN (without NAT/PAT/etc...).

I obviously read Jessie Frazelle's [blog post](https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/ips-for-all-the-things/) and a lot of others post here and everywhere like :

- [How to set a docker container's iP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641828/how-to-set-a-docker-containers-ip)
- [How to assign specific IP to container and make that accessible outside of VM host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218621/how-to-assign-specific-ip-to-container-and-make-that-accessible-outside-of-vm-ho)

and so much more, but nothing came out; my containers still have IP addresses "inside" my docker host, and are not reachable for others computers on my LAN.

Reading Jessie Frazelle's blog post, I thought (since she uses public IP) we can do what I want to do?

**Edit**: Indeed, if I do something like :

```
network create --subnet 192.168.1.0/24 --gateway 192.168.1.1 homenet
docker run --rm -it --net homenet --ip 192.168.1.100 nginx
```

The new interface on the docker host (br-[a-z0-9]+) take the '--gateway' IP, which is my router IP. And the same IP on two computers on the network... BOOM

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you on Linux, or using docker through a boot2docker VM?

Comment: Such a fool ! I forgot the most important ! I'm on Linux (Debian 8).

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I've had a lot of complex problems related to this over the past few weeks. Specifically reaching the container from _outside_ the subnet. I have since moved away from that as a result of my problems, but I am glad this post exists in the event I need to do that again.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**EDIT :** This solution is now useless. Since version 1.12, Docker provides two network drivers : macvlan and ipvlan. They allow assigning static IP from the LAN network. See the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39285950/5515387).

---

After looking for [people who have the same problem](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20758), we went to a workaround :

## Sum up :

- (V)LAN is 192.168.1.0/24
- Default Gateway (= router) is 192.168.1.1
- Multiple Docker Hosts
- Note : We have two NIC : eth0 and eth1 (which is dedicated to Docker)

## What do we want :

We want to have containers with ip in the 192.168.1.0/24 network (like computers) without any NAT/PAT/translation/port-forwarding/etc...

## Problem

When doing this :

```
network create --subnet 192.168.1.0/24 --gateway 192.168.1.1 homenet
```

we are able to give containers the IP we want to, **but** the bridge created by docker (`br-[a-z0-9]+`) will have the IP 192.168.1.1, which is our router.

## Solution

#### 1. Setup the Docker Network

Use the `DefaultGatewayIPv4` parameter :

```
docker network create --subnet 192.168.1.0/24 --aux-address "DefaultGatewayIPv4=192.168.1.1" homenet
```

By default, Docker will give to the bridge interface (`br-[a-z0-9]+`) the first IP, which might be already taken by another machine. The solution is to use the `--gateway` parameter to tell docker to assign a arbitrary IP (which is available) :

```
docker network create --subnet 192.168.1.0/24 --aux-address "DefaultGatewayIPv4=192.168.1.1" --gateway=192.168.1.200 homenet
```

We can specify the bridge name by adding `-o com.docker.network.bridge.name=br-home-net` to the previous command.

#### 2. Bridge the bridge !

Now we have a bridge (`br-[a-z0-9]+`) created by Docker. We need to bridge it to a physical interface (in my case I have to NIC, so I'm using eth1 for that):

```
brctl addif br-home-net eth1
```

#### 3. Delete the bridge IP

We can now delete the IP address from the bridge, since we don't need one :

```
ip a del 192.168.1.200/24 dev br-home-net
```

The IP `192.168.1.200` can be used as bridge on multiple docker host, since we don't use it, and we remove it.

Comment: how can I reverse `brctl addif br-home-net eth1`?  Locked myself out of SSH and need to ask someone to make the fix :)

Comment: @Duplexia : You can do a `brctl delif br-home-net eth1`.

Comment: Thank you that was very very useful, I just want to point that if you lost your internet connection, you have to add your default gateway manually to your route table: sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1

Comment: is there a way to achieve this with DHCP? I'm trying to assign ISP's DHCP IP address for containers.

Comment: Since Docker 1.12, there is both macvlan and ipvlan drivers. They make this solution useless. And since Docker 17.06, I think you can assign IP addresses out of a DHCP Pool with the macvlan driver.

Answer (score 7):

Docker now supports **Macvlan** and **IPvlan** network drivers. The Docker documentation for both network drivers can be found [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/experimental/vlan-networks.md).

With both drivers you can implement your desired scenario (configure a container to behave like a virtual machine in bridge mode):

- **Macvlan**: Allows a single physical network interface (master device) to have an arbitrary number of slave devices, each with it's own MAC adresses.

  Requires Linux kernel v3.9–3.19 or 4.0+.
- **IPvlan**: Allows you to create an arbitrary number of slave devices for your master device which all share the same MAC address.

  Requires Linux kernel v4.2+ (support for earlier kernels exists but is buggy).

  See the [kernel.org IPVLAN Driver HOWTO](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ipvlan.txt) for further information.

Container connectivity is achieved by putting one of the slave devices into the network namespace of the container to be configured. The master devices remains on the host operating system (default namespace).

As a rule of thumb you should use the IPvlan driver if the Linux host that is connected to the external switch / router has a policy configured that allows only one MAC per port. That's often the case in VMWare ESXi environments!

**Another important thing to remember (Macvlan and IPvlan):** Traffic to and from the master device cannot be sent to and from slave devices. If you need to enable master to slave communication see section "*Communication with the host (default-ns)*" in the "*IPVLAN – The beginning*" paper published by one of the IPvlan authors (Mahesh Bandewar).

Comment: Nice. +1. I'll have to test that out.

Comment: Could You share some tutorial how to configure this with Macvlan? I would much like to read some article because it is hard for me to configure by myself. It was easy with Virtualbox to make it obtain IP from WiFi router - there is configuration on virtual network card, so I could define my own MAC. I am new to Docker and with it I just can't manage.

Comment: See [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-macvlan/) for Docker's Macvlan documentation @Marecky. [This](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-macvlan/#macvlan-bridge-mode-example-usage) section should actually show you how assign unique MAC / IP addresses to each container.

Answer (score 4):

***Use the official Docker driver:***

As of [Docker v1.12.0-rc2](https://github.com/docker/docker/releases/tag/v1.12.0-rc2), the new MACVLAN driver is now available in an official Docker release:

> - MacVlan driver is out of experimental [#23524](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/23524)

These new drivers have been [well documented by the author(s), with usage examples](https://gist.github.com/nerdalert/c0363c15d20986633fda).

End of the day it should provide similar functionality, be easier to setup, and with fewer bugs / other quirks.

***Seeing Containers on the Docker host:***

Only caveat with the new official macvlan driver is that the docker host machine cannot see / communicate with its own containers. Which might be desirable or not, depending on your specific situation.

This issue can be worked-around if you have more than 1 NIC on your docker host machine. And both NICs are connected to your LAN. Then can either A) dedicate 1 of your docker hosts's 2 nics to be for docker exclusively. And be using the remaining nic for the host to access the LAN.

Or B) by adding specific routes to only those containers you need to access via the 2nd NIC. For example:

```
sudo route add -host $container_ip gw $lan_router_ip $if_device_nic2
```

Method A) is useful if you want to access all your containers from the docker host and you have multiple hardwired links.

Wheras method B) is useful if you only require access to a few specific containers from the docker host. Or if your 2nd NIC is a wifi card and  would be much slower for handling all of your LAN traffic. For example on a laptop computer.

***Installation:***

If cannot see the pre-release `-rc2` candidate on ubuntu 16.04, temporarily add or modify this line to your /etc/apt/sources.list to say:

```
deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial testing
```

instead of `main` (which is stable releases).

Answer (score 3):

I no longer recommended this solution. So it's been removed. It was [using bridge driver and brctrl](https://gist.github.com/dreamcat4/bc202ae175b367bcbe693da7a52851af)
.

There is a better and official driver now. See other answer on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36470828/287510

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using macvlan. It starts a web server at http://10.0.2.1/.

These commands and Docker Compose file work on QNAP and QNAP's Container Station. Notice that QNAP's network interface is `qvs0`.

## Commands:

The blog post "[Using Docker macvlan networks](http://blog.oddbit.com/2018/03/12/using-docker-macvlan-networks/)"<sup>[[1]](https://web.archive.org/web/20180414105417/http://blog.oddbit.com/2018/03/12/using-docker-macvlan-networks/)[[2]](http://archive.is/gBDMe)</sup> by Lars Kellogg-Stedman explains what the commands mean.

```
docker network create -d macvlan -o parent=qvs0 --subnet 10.0.0.0/8 --gateway 10.0.0.1 --ip-range 10.0.2.0/24 --aux-address "host=10.0.2.254" macvlan0
ip link del macvlan0-shim link qvs0 type macvlan mode bridge
ip link add macvlan0-shim link qvs0 type macvlan mode bridge
ip addr add 10.0.2.254/32 dev macvlan0-shim
ip link set macvlan0-shim up
ip route add 10.0.2.0/24 dev macvlan0-shim

docker run --network="macvlan0" --ip=10.0.2.1 -p 80:80 nginx
```

## Docker Compose

Use version 2 because version 3 does not support the other network configs, such as `gateway`, `ip_range`, and `aux_address`.

```
version: "2.3"

services:
    HTTPd:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80/tcp"
            - "80:80/udp"
        networks:
            macvlan0:
                ipv4_address: "10.0.2.1"

networks:
    macvlan0:
        driver: macvlan
        driver_opts:
            parent: qvs0
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: "10.0.0.0/8"
                  gateway: "10.0.0.1"
                  ip_range: "10.0.2.0/24"
                  aux_address: "host=10.0.2.254"
```

Answer (score -1):

It's possible map a physical interface into a container via [`pipework`](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework).

[Connect a container to a local physical interface](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework#connect-a-container-to-a-local-physical-interface)

```
pipework eth2 $(docker run -d hipache /usr/sbin/hipache) 50.19.169.157/24
pipework eth3 $(docker run -d hipache /usr/sbin/hipache) 107.22.140.5/24
```

There may be a native way now but I haven't looked into that for the 1.10 release.

Comment: The drawback of pipework is: we can't see the containers on same host machine. So a native solution might be preferable. (and faster to assign IP addresses / less buggy).